# Is there a way to create multiple subnets in AWS using terraform using cidr range

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have 2 front-end and back-end subnets, currently I am passing the subnet range as variable, but is there any way to pick the free cidr range in a VPC through terraform?

Answer (score 0):

Hashicorp has a module available to help with subnet CIDRs https://registry.terraform.io/modules/hashicorp/subnets/cidr/1.0.0

```
module "subnet_addrs" {
  source = "hashicorp/subnets/cidr"

  base_cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/8"
  networks = [
    {
      name     = "foo"
      new_bits = 8
    },
    {
      name     = "bar"
      new_bits = 8
    },
    {
      name     = "baz"
      new_bits = 4
    },
    {
      name     = "beep"
      new_bits = 8
    },
    {
      name     = "boop"
      new_bits = 8
    },
  ]
}
```

which will provide a `network_cidr_blocks` output with the values

```
{
  foo  = "10.0.0.0/16"
  bar  = "10.1.0.0/16"
  baz  = "10.16.0.0/12"
  beep = "10.32.0.0/16"
  boop = "10.33.0.0/16"
}
```

You can also calculate it from the VPC CIDR yourself using some built-in functions, `cidrsubnets` and `cidrsubnet`

https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/cidrsubnets.html

```
> cidrsubnets("10.0.0.0/8", 8, 8, 4, 8, 8)
[
  "10.0.0.0/16",
  "10.1.0.0/16",
  "10.16.0.0/12",
  "10.32.0.0/16",
  "10.33.0.0/16",
]
```